# Spatial data on cancer

Tags: data-request, medical

I have to perform a autoregressive [CAR bayesian model](http://www.statsref.com/HTML/index.html?car_models.html) on some cancer spatial data.

I have no clue where to find open dataset with spatial information about cancer data.

Answer (score 3):

NIH's National Cancer Institute runs [Geographic Information Systems and Science for Cancer Control (gis.cancer.gov) subdomain](https://gis.cancer.gov/), which provides resources for interactive mapping, exploring, and downloading, geographically based cancer related information. Essentially its a service to prove/provide why spatial context matters, particularly regarding health, in the areas of environmental exposure, built & social environment, and access to health services.